# Not able to add data in MongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, google-oauth, passport.js

This is OAuth (Google Authentication) flow. I want to authenticate the user and add the user (if the user is new). But the collection is not updating.

**Code for User Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

// Property Schema defined for users model
const userSchema = new Schema({
  googleId: String,
});

// Create/Update a Collection
mongoose.model("users", userSchema);
```

**Code for Authentication:**

```
const passport = require("passport");
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const keys = require("../config/keys");

const User = mongoose.model("users");



  

  [passport.use(
      new GoogleStrategy(
        {
          clientID: keys.googleClientID,
          clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
          callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
        },
        (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
          User.findOne({
            googleId: profile.id,
          }).then((existingUser) => {
            if (existingUser) {
              // Not a new user, already registered
            } else {
              // Register a new User
              new User({ googleId: profile.id }).save();
            }
          });
        }
      )
    );
```

Image link for MONGO DB Dashboard

[Click on the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uzHK.png)

Comment: It looks like u forgot to connect to the database with mongoose.connect("hosting"), also I have no idea why are you requiring mongoose 2 times

Comment: @RobinGrundel The authentication and userSchema are two different files. Also, in index file I have mentioned mongoose.connect("<KEY>")

Answer (score 0):

I think how you are requiring `User` model is the problem.
Instead of
`const User = mongoose.model("users");`

Try requiring it and use it in your strategy:
`const UserModel = require('./UserModel.js')`

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install findorcreate

const findOrCreate = require('mongoose-findorcreate');

userSchema.plugin(findOrCreate);

// Replace your google strategy code with this one below

passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: <your clientID>,
    clientSecret: <your clientSecret>,
    callbackURL: '<your callback url>',
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
    User.findOrCreate({googleId: profile.id}, function(err, user) {
      return cb(err, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).